# Delicious - Getting links in a stack via API

Tags: delicious-api

I have a user in delicious, and I have created a new stack.
I am trying to get the links in that stack via the API. Preferably as an xml feed..
I haven't found any documented way to do this. Is this supported at all?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to Paul from Delicious:

> Hi Itay! There currently are no RSS feeds or API support for stacks. These are features we may look into adding in the future. - Paul

Source: https://www.facebook.com/delicious/posts/10150714852032205?notif_t=feed_comment